# What makes a program flow different from a program path?

Tags: programming-languages

Program flow and path are discriminated in the literature of program analysis. However, I have failed to find a formal definition of program flow and path. Can anyone please point me to some authentic literature, e.g. research paper or popular books? Also, an example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never head of the phrase "program flow". Please provide context about where you saw it used (e.g., can you provide a full quotation that uses it, can you credit the source, can you share the context?).

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't find any definition of the word path.  What research did you do?  It's in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory).

Comment: @D.W. I am referring to "flow" and "path" in the light of program analysis in general. Here's a bit of context to relate to: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lin/papers/cgo11.pdf

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide that context and give a more specific example.  I don't immediately see anywhere that uses the word "flow" on its own.  I do see "flow-sensitive", but you can't understand what "flow-sensitive" means by asking what "flow" means.  Also, the meaning of "flow-sensitive" is described in many places.  Have you done any research?  Where have you looked?  Have you read standard textbooks on program analysis?  Have you read the citations after the first reference to "flow-sensitive"?  There's little point in us repeating material that is readily findable.